# Does the order of table parameters matter in MySQL queries

Tags: mysql

I find that when I'm trying to make a mysqli query, it will fail unless I order the parameters in a certain way.

```
//Example that causes error (focus on order of AUTO_INCREMENT and UNSIGNED)

<?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");

$query = "CREATE TABLE colors (
id INT(2) AUTO_INCREMENT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
color1 varchar(20) NOT NULL,
color2 varchar(20) NOT NULL
)";

$con->query($query);
?>
```

However, when `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `UNSIGNED` switch places, the query is successful. The same thing seems to happen to me when the `PRIMARY KEY` parameter is not the last parameter listed. Does the order matter?

Comment: Those are not things I would exactly call "parameters" exactly; but yes there is for the most part an expected order to them. It can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html).

Comment: Please accept an answer by clicking on the check mark below the up/down vote triangles if it resolves your original question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please take a look at the MySQL documentation for the `CREATE TABLE` syntax:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Specifically this section for column_definition:

```
column_definition:
    data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]
      [AUTO_INCREMENT] [UNIQUE [KEY] | [PRIMARY] KEY]
      [COMMENT 'string']
      [COLUMN_FORMAT {FIXED|DYNAMIC|DEFAULT}]
      [STORAGE {DISK|MEMORY|DEFAULT}]
      [reference_definition]
  | data_type [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS (expression)
      [VIRTUAL | STORED] [UNIQUE [KEY]] [COMMENT comment]
      [NOT NULL | NULL] [[PRIMARY] KEY]
```

The format and order matters.  The documentation can help you to determine the correct order of parameters.